# Eliminar todos los registros relacionados a una llave primaria en oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo una base de datos y quiero eliminar todos los datos de un usuario dada su cedula por pantalla, pero al hacer el proceso y ejecutar el respectivo comando de sql para eliminar me muestra lo siguiente:

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-02292: integrity constraint (PROYECTO.FK_PACIENTE_DETALLE_ASIGNACION) violated - child record found in ...
```

que puedo hacer para solucionar ese error.
o bueno, la pregunta mas en general seria, como elimino una llave primaria en todas  las tablas donde exista conexion con esa llave primaria.

Comment: @Aprendiz yo lo entiendo al reves, que esta tratando de borrar en la tabla padre, si no en la hija le dejaria. Y si es oracle, el padre no va a tener la integridad de las hijas. Habria que buscar en las tablas del sistema los constrain de la base de datos.

Comment: Bien ahi @gbianchi entiendo ;)

Comment: Las bases de datos relacionales usan lo que se llama algo así como `integridad referencial`. Significa que no te va a dejar eliminar un registro de una tabla `hijo` mientras exista en tabla `padre`. Esto es muy lógico ya que si elimina el `hijo`, la tabla `padre` que tiene ese `hijo` ya no podría acceder a esa información por que se eliminó

Comment: @JuanRom la explicacion esta bien.. pero es totalmente al reves.. el hijo siempre se puede borrar.. lo que no se puede borrar es un padre que tiene un hijo ;)

Comment: @gbianchi efectivamente, acabo de probar a eliminar un hijo y si se dejo facilmente, pero volvi a intentar con el padre pero nada

Comment: pero mi pregunta es, si existe forma de eliminar eso de forma total, evitando eso de la integridad referencial

Comment: si. elimina de todas las tablas hijos las referencias a la integridad referencial (el error dice de que tablas vienen).. y listo... pero el problema es que te van a quedar montones de registros huerfanos.. y alguien puso la integridad ahi por algo no?

Comment: @gbianchi si, me hice lio, gracias, ya lo edito..

Comment: @gbianchi no conozco mucho de sql aun pero seria muy nefasto si en el case donde estoy haciendo la opcion de eliminar registro, añado varias setencias de delete eliminando en cada 1, las posibles tablas donde esten los hijos y por ultimo al padre?

Comment: aunque no lo creas, jose, no es nefasto, **es** lo que corresponde hacer y lo correcto

Comment: suponiendo que sea correcto entonces, segun el orden en que yo ponga esas sentencias, es el orden con que se ira eliminando el registro que yo quiero?

Comment: @gbianchi pero por ejemplo tengo `detalleVenta` y `producto`, `detalleVenta` seria el `padre` y `producto` el `hijo`, ya que `detalleVenta` tiene `producto`, y en este sentido no me va a dejar eliminar un `producto` de la tabla `producto`. Creo que tengo un problema de conceptos con respecto a `padre` e `hijo`

Comment: @gbianchi despues de tanto averiguar ya descubri la razon del problema, al crear la base de datos de mi trabajo, en las tablas nunca defini la restriccion cascade, con ella me deja borrar desde el valor padre y no tengo que eliminar directamente a los hijos, el cascade lo hace solo